# How can I change Java version for QGIS?

Tags: qgis, java

I have a custom made plugin for QGIS, which uses Java JDK (running on Win7x64). If the JAR file is run through command prompt, everything works great, but when the same command is used in plugin, it shows this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" 
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.initReaderIDs(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Class;)V
at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.initReaderIDs(Native Method)
at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.<clinit>(JPEGImageReader.java:91)
at
com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReaderSpi.createReaderInstance(JPEGImageReaderSpi.java:85)
at javax.imageio.spi.ImageReaderSpi.createReaderInstance(ImageReaderSpi.java:320)
at javax.imageio.ImageIO$ImageReaderIterator.next(ImageIO.java:529)
at javax.imageio.ImageIO$ImageReaderIterator.next(ImageIO.java:513)
at com.geokods.App.main(App.java:262)
```

I fount that QGIS uses different Java version:

```
java version "1.7.0_67"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_67-b01)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode)
```

vs. CMD:

```
java version "1.8.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)
```

How can I fix this?

UPDATE:

Problem is partially solved by appending command with:

```
-version:1.8.0_45
```

Now plugin works as it should. But still, there should be a way to overwrite the old Java version.

UPDATE 2:

Tried to set JAVA_HOME by adding `set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45` to bin\qgis.bat. Did not help.

Comment: How have you installed QGIS? If you use OSGeo4W I would try to find the .bat file that is setting the JAVA_HOME environment variable http://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/wiki/pkg-java. Perhaps setting your preferred version with `SET JAVA_HOME=path_to_your_jre8` on the last line before the "start qgis" line in OSGeo4W/bin/qgis.bat would work as well as an override.

Comment: Already tried- not helping.

Comment: Add to your question exactly what you tried - which bat did you edit. The execution order of the batch files when launching OSGeo4W programs is not so clear for me and it may need some experimenting to find the latest SET.